# Is it possible to debug a fairseq task with vscode or some other tools?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, fairseq

I am using fairseq to run a customized task with command line tool `fairseq-train ${data} {args}`. Is it possible to enter debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The original command is `fairseq-train ${args}`.
I found this is equivalent to `python ${PATH-TO-FAIRSEQ_ROOT}/fairseq_cli/train.py ${args}`.

If you know how to [debug in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging), then just point the "program" parameter to the (absolute) path of `fairseq_cli/train.py`, and put all arguments after the "args", in the `launch.json` file.